# Como tener el valor de un checkbox con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, checkbox

Tengo una consulta o query como les guste decirle, y en la consulta que le hago a la tabla seria algo así como esto:

```
$d151="select * from temporal where ncuenta>'399' and LENGTH(ncuenta)>3";
$db1=$dbh->prepare($d151);
$db1->execute();
```

la consulta me funciona de maravilla sin queja alguna los campos de la tabla son

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ncuenta varchar (100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
dcuenta varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
d151 TINYINT(1) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
```

por ahí todavía va todo bien.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>N°cuenta</th>
<th>Descripción</th>
<th>Agrega o Elimina</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ($ver=$db1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $ver['ncuenta'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $ver['dcuenta'];?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"id="agrega" onChange="agrega(<?php echo $ver['id'];?>);"
<?php if($ver['d151']==1){echo "checked='checked'";};?>>AGREGAR A CUENTAS</td>
</tr>
<?php };?>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Ok aquí es donde la mula donde boto a Juan, cuando en el script le digo cual es el valor del check me sale que es true pero cuando le doy click para que no haga check o quitarle el check siempre me sale el valor a true

Comment: cambia el id="agrega" por id="agrega[<?=$ver["id]?>"

Comment: pero eso me daría por ejemplo agrega1 o agrega44 etc y lo que quiero es que me diga cuando fue hecho un check para cambiar el dato en la tabla $ver['d151] y me quede con 1 si es marcada o 0 si es desmarcada

Comment: y como identificarias que registro fue cambiado?

Comment: con el campo $ver['d151'] si es 1 es true y si es cero es false, entonces cuando se le da oprimir al checkbox y queda marcado por medio de el javascript le actualizo al campo para que me quede uno en la tabla si lo desmarco entonces en la tabla me queda cero, no se si me estoy explicando bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final puede resolver el dilema de otra manera con todo el codigo anterior solo le cambio esta parte 
`<td>
<?php if($ver['d151']==1){ $a="0||".$ver['id'];?>
<button class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok"onclick="agrega1('<?php echo $a;?>');"></button> CUENTA AGREGADA
<?php }else{$b="1||".$ver['id'];?>
<button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"onclick="agrega1('<?php echo $b;?>');"></button> AGREGAR CUENTA<?php };?>
</td>`

y asi tengo los datos que necesito si es cero entonces es una cuenta que se desmarco y si es uno es una cuenta que se marco. Pongo la respuesta porque talvez a otras personas le puede funcionar la idea.